# NotImplementedError when running dbt version check on installing dbt-bigquery

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, dbt

I am trying to install dbt bigquery in my Windows system by running the following pip commands -

```
pip install dbt-bigquery
```

Installation has finished successfully but when I run the dbt --version command here is the error I am getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 198,
> in *run_module_as_main   File "", line 88, in *run_code
> File
> "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Scripts\dbt.exe_*main**.py",
> line 4, in    File
> "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\dbt\main.py",
> line 2, in 
> from dbt.logger import log_cache_events, log_manager   File "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\dbt\logger.py",
> line 16, in 
> from dbt.dataclass_schema import dbtClassMixin   File "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\dbt\dataclass_schema.py",
> line 15, in 
> from mashumaro import DataClassDictMixin   File "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\mashumaro_*init**.py",
> line 4, in 
> from mashumaro.serializer.json import DataClassJSONMixin   File "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\mashumaro\serializer\json.py",
> line 28, in 
> class DataClassJSONMixin(DataClassDictMixin):   File "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\mashumaro\serializer\base\dict.py",
> line 16, in **init_subclass**
> builder.add_from_dict()   File "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\mashumaro\serializer\base\metaprogramming.py",
> line 270, in add_from_dict
> pre_deserialize = self.get_declared_hook(**PRE_DESERIALIZE**)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\mashumaro\serializer\base\metaprogramming.py",
> line 255, in get_declared_hook
> if not is_dataclass_dict_mixin(cls):
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\mashumaro\meta\helpers.py",
> line 247, in is_dataclass_dict_mixin
> return type_name(t) == DataClassDictMixinPath
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\mashumaro\meta\helpers.py",
> line 93, in type_name
> elif is_generic(t) and not is_type_origin:
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\1354750\Documents\code\env\Lib\site-packages\mashumaro\meta\helpers.py",
> line 161, in is_generic
> raise NotImplementedError NotImplementedError

Prior to the dbt command, I am running this in a Python virtual environment in the 'code' folder using the following commands.

```
python -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

Can someone help me what the error is pointing at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an incompatible Python version installed in the system (3.11.x) which was causing the error. Reference - [What version of Python can I use?](https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/core/install-python-compatibility). The issue is now resolved.